# Converting PySpark Dataframe rows to dictionaries and running functions on these dictionaries

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe df_base and I would like to run a function 'encoder' that takes in every row converted into the form of a dictionary as input.

So if I have

```
df_dict = df_base \
    .rdd \
    .map(lambda row: {row[0]: row[1]}) \
    .collect()
```

I want to run `encoder` on the rows mapped to dictionaries. What is the ideal way to do this that doesn't also cause overflow errors in Spark?

Originally I tried `df_list_of_dict = [encoder(row.asDict()) for row in df_base.collect()]` but I got errors such as

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException:Job aborted due to stage failure:Total size of serialized results of 40 tasks (4.0 GB)is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GB)
```

Is there any way to get this to work properly without stage failure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use it within the `map`.

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: encoder({row[0], row[1]})).collect()
```